# How would this hierarchy for knowledge representation be extended?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, data-representation

I've tried making a hierarchy of all forms of knowledge - including physical objects, numbers, procedures etc. How could this be improved? How would a sentence such as "Jack is producing music sitting on a tree" fall into this chart? *Jack* would go into humans, *tree* into place , but where would *music* go? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are and were various efforts to represent knowledge - one of them is a set of specifications around the Resource Description Framework (RDF):

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework

RDF is a base language which is used to define also **ontologies** which defines the types, properties, and relationships of the entities within a particular domain, providing a structured framework for **organizing knowledge about that domain**. Web Ontology Language (OWL) provides concepts to define ontologies:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language

And one of the ontologies is MusicOWL:

- https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3106426.3110325

See OWL ontologies for inspiration and/or reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any experience in this field but looking at it from purely linguistic and logical way, you can put "producing " totally into work. Or maybe branch out your `"objects"` into different kinds like `"products"->{"tech","healthcare"...}` etc and "`art objects"->{"music","paintings"...}`

But yeah you can argue that this is a little more specific just to fit in the sentence.

Comment: But how do i represent actions and adjectives? _Producing_ could come under actions, couldn't it? And if an adjective such as _melodious_ was present in the sentence- how would that be classified?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a direct answer to your question, but I think I know where you would get more information on this tops. If I am not mistaken, you are trying to develop an ontology.

> In computer science and information science, an ontology formally represents knowledge as a set of concepts within a domain, and the relationships among those concepts. It can be used to reason about the entities within that domain and may be used to describe the domain.

The most general ontology is developed at [Cycorp](http://cyc.com/), although the whole ontology is not freely available, a (large) subset of the onotlogy is available by [Opencyc](http://www.opencyc.org/). They have an instalaltion prepared, which enables you to make queries to the ontology via a web-browser. Maybe you should explore this ontology and get some new ideas where to go next.